# Is there a way to perform Square Root and trigonometric functions in SQL lite on an Android app?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am currently building an Android mobile application that requires me to build in complex mathematical functions. The platform I use to build this app uses SQLite for its internal DB and it supports custom SQL statements. The built in math functions of the application building software are very basic, so I wanted to try and use custom SQL statements to get what I need instead.

I have tried the SQRT function to try and get what I need, but nothing I do seems to work. I wish I had more that I could provide you, but the platform I use doesn't have any internal errors. It either works, or it doesn't.

While researching I read that SQRT doesn't necessarily work in SQLite, but these were mostly really old threads and I'd like to know if it can somehow be done.

Answer (score 0):

The list of SQLite math functions is at https://www.sqlite.org/lang_mathfunc.html

Sqrt is included (I originally didn't see it and uggested using pow as a replacement)

Comment: I saw this information as well, and I saw that SQRT is included in that list. I have no idea however if the amalgamation is compiled with  -DSQLITE_ENABLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS. So this raises more questions than answers.

Comment: @NiksAanDeWashand If you're desperate for it you can include your own version of libsql in your app and link against that.  Then you know what its compiled with.  I've done that before when I needed certain flags turned on.  Otherwise the best way to test is just to try it and see if sqlite throws an error.

Comment: No current version of Android is going to offer a version of sqlite new enough to support those.